# How to conditional format a row by current month and year on google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

[image: e.g. row 50 would be black font]

How to conditional format the current (month and year) row's font be black?
Thank you! God bless (1 Corinthians 15 KJV)!

Comment: The dates start at A21. This formula worked, hope it helps!
=TEXT($A21,"MMM YYYY")=TEXT(TODAY(),"MMM YYYY")
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

custom formula:

```
=TEXT($A21, "MMM YYYY")=TEXT(TODAY(), "MMM YYYY")
```